# How to Refresh Auth data after update

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

i m working classifieds controller

this is code

```
   public function create_add(){
          if(!empty($this->data))
         {
             if($this->Classified->save($this->data)){
               $this->User->save(array('id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'),'pending_attempts'=>$this->Auth->User('pending_attempts')-1));
             $data = $this->User->read();
             $this->Auth->login($data);
             }
            }
    }
```

i want to updating the 'pending_attempts' column in user table , for example:

pending_attempts = 10;

Every time run this code, pending_attempts will be 10 - 1, and always resulting in 9.

After login only time code work and update the database , if i again run that code create_add() it always show pending_attempts =9

**Problem** is that how to refresh Auth data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of my question , that code working fine for me

```
public function create_add()
 {
    if(!empty($this->data))
      {
        if($this->Classified->save($this->data))
          {

         $user_data = $this->User->find('first',array('fields' => array('id','pending_attempts'),'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'))));
         $this->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
         $this->data['User']['pending_attempts']= $user_data['User']['pending_attempts']-1;
         $this->User->save($this->data);
       }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are no updating the 'pending_attempts' , for example:

pending_attempts = 10;

Every time you run this code, pending_attempts will be 10 - 1, and always resulting in 9.

```
'pending_attempts'=>$this->Auth->User('pending_attempts')-1)
```

Looking at you code, i think you are trying to update user Auth session, but i think it's no working:

```
$this->Auth->login($data);
```

take a look [here](http://milesj.me/blog/read/31/Refreshing-The-Auths-Session)

Comment: i have used that function in app controller but not refreshing auth

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of the tricks to refresh in my appplication i have done in last year.But nothing helped me.So why i can give you an alternative.Fetch data from table at first with user_id which is in session.And then use it as data for operation.....Happy coding  bro...

Answer (score 0):

Your method should looks like:

```
public function create_add()
{
     if(!empty($this->data))
     {
         if($this->Classified->save($this->data))
         {
                 $user_data = $this->User->find(null, $this->Auth->User('id'));
                 $user_data['User']['pending_attempts'] -= 1;
                 $this->User->save($user_data);
                 $this->Auth->login($user_data);
         }
     }
}
```

I checked it and it is working. Kindly ask if it is not working for you.

Comment: thanks for reply , but i m getting error in that line $user_data['User']['pending_attempts'] -= 1;
Undefined index: User and Undefined index: pending_attempts

Comment: also getting error on that line $user_data = $this->User->find(null, $this->Auth->User('id')); SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'User.117' in 'field list' that's nothing is print

Comment: I think you are missing something. Please check it once. You can also try it with $this->User->findById($this->Auth->user('id'));